# What is the difference between :before and ::before?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just saw a CSS code that included `::before` tag. I looked at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:before) to see what the `::before` is but I really didn't understand it.

Can someone explain how it works?

Does it make a DOM element before what we select by CSS?

Comment: Afaik, the CSS working group decided to prefix pseudo-elements with an additional colon to differentiate them from pseudo-classes which have only one colon.

Comment: ... and since double-colon notation isn't implemented in IE8, we'll have to wait 'till it's flushed from the market (like in 2016 or so), before we can start using `::before`. Great job, Microsoft `-.-`

Comment: Pseudo-elements have been around since CSS1. The first pseudo-elements were `:first-letter` and `:first-line`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This distinguishes pseudo elements from pseudo classes.

The difference between pseudo classes and pseudo elements is described at http://www.d.umn.edu/~lcarlson/csswork/selectors/pseudo_dif.html

Comment: The ::before notation (with two colons) was introduced in CSS3 in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept the notation :before introduced in CSS 2. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before As before is a pseudo ELEMENT and not a pseudo CLASS (like :hover) two colons is better (thus following the CSS3 standard).

Answer (score 90):

According to those docs, they are equivalent:

```
element:before  { style properties }  /* CSS2 syntax */

element::before { style properties }  /* CSS3 syntax */
```

The only difference is that the double colon is used in CSS3, whereas the single colon is the legacy version.

**Reasoning:**

> The ::before notation was introduced in CSS 3 in order to establish a
>   discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. Browsers
>   also accept the notation :before introduced in CSS 2.

Answer (score 18):

They essentially mean the same thing. The `::` was introduced in CSS3 to help descriminate between pseudo elements (like :before and :after) and pseudo classes (like :link and :hover).

Answer (score 6):

I checked out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3abefore) and [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/), and the best I could come up with is that `::` is used for **structural** changes, and `:` is used for **styling**.

They are currently interchangeable for compatibility reasons.

It appears to separate `:link` (for instance), which styles a `<a>`, from `:before` (which is a **structural** change).

`:` is for styling, `::` is for structure.

Comment: How are we changing the Structure when for example we write `.text::selection{ background: red;}`?!! It is a Pseudo-Classes and there are no structure changes... It is just about styling...

Answer (score 2):

One is the CSS2 (:before) way and the other is CSS3 (::before). Currently they are interchangeable in browsers that support CSS2 & CSS3.

Here's a good explanation: http://www.impressivewebs.com/before-after-css3/